# Sort Java Map output in ascending order

Tags: java

I made this quick code for a class and I got everything to work fine as far as reading the text file and printing it out, but I can't figure out how to get it to print out in ascending order. The goal is to read a file and print out the number of times that word appears and sort it by the number of times it appears.

```
public class Analyser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        File file = new File("src/txt.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        Map<String, Long> counts = new HashMap<>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


            String[] words = line.split("[\\s.;,?:!()\"]+");
            for (String word : words) {
                word = word.trim();
                if (word.length() > 0) {
                    if (counts.containsKey(word)) {
                        counts.put(word, counts.get(word) + 1);
                    } else {
                        counts.put(word, 1L);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you intend to sort the map alphabetically, or by the number of times each word appears.  If you want it sorted alphabetically, then your best bet is to use a map that keeps its data always sorted, such as a `TreeMap`.  So if you change `HashMap` to `TreeMap` on the fourth line of the method, this should just work.

Answer (score 1):

A `HashMap` has no defined order. Maps which implement the `SortedMap` interface, such as `TreeMap`, do have an order defined by a `Comparator`, but they're ordered by *keys*, not *values*. And then there's `LinkedHashMap`, which maintains *insertion* order (or *access* order, if you want that instead). You could make use of `LinkedHashMap` if you make sure to insert the elements in the desired order. That, of course, means you still need to iterate your original map in the desired order somehow.

But I think, in your case, it does not matter so much that the map has the order you want. You only want order when you *print* the results. And you only do this once, so there's no need for some kind of caching of the order. So, I would probably just use an intermediate list or a stream.

Example using list:

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> list = new ArrayList<>(counts.entrySet());
list.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());

for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : list) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Example using stream:

```java
counts.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .forEachOrdered(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
```

The `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` call returns a `Comparator` which is used to sort the elements. Specifically, it will sort by the *natural order* of the values of the entries. A `Long`'s natural order is from smallest to largest. If you want a different order, then pass whatever `Comparator` you need to get that order (which may involve writing your own implementation). Though if you simply want to sort from largest to smallest (i.e., reversed natural order), just use `Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())` instead.

---

I also recommend, at least in "real" code, that you use *try-with-resources* instead of manually closing the reader. For example:

```java
File file = new File("src/txt.txt");
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
  // use 'br' here (the remainder of you code, minus the 'br.close()' call
}
```

When that `try` block exits, the resource referenced by `br` will be automatically closed for you, and in a safer way than simply calling `br.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since a `TreeMap` only sorts on the key and not the values, it won't work as you want to sort based on the count which is a value. Since you have already created your map, the easiest ways is to sort it and print as follows:

- stream the `entrySet()` and then sort using the Entry's `comparingByValue` comparator.

```
counts.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you want to retain the sorted order in a different map, you can do it like this and then print the new map.  Using a `LinkedHashMap` preserves the order.

- sort as before
- but collect in a map

  - first argument is the entry's key
  - second is the entry's value.
  - third is a BinaryOperator (Not used here but syntactically required)
  - fourth is a supplier which makes the map a LinkedHashMap

```
Map<String, Long> sortedMap = 
   counts.entrySet().stream().sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a,
                LinkedHashMap::new));
// now print the map
sortedMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```